# regex isn't working

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# trying to use regex on a file path

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"batchFile.bat");
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"D:\folder1\folder(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d)\setup.exe", @"D:\folder1\folder" + newVersion + @"\setup.exe");
File.WriteAllText(@"batchFile.bat", result);
```

So the original file path could be

```
D:\folder1\folder123.234.56.7\setup.exe
```

and I'm trying to use regex so I can change it to any other version number such as 12.3.456.78

When I run this code it doesnt change

Comment: You also need to write `result` back to the file.

Comment: Check out http://regexr.com/ it's a nice online tool for building, validating, and learning about RegEx expressions.

Comment: yeah I have it writing back to the file, I'll edit my question to include that

Comment: i have been using regexr.com and it find's the values i'm looking for but when I use it specifically in this code it doesn't work

Comment: you should escape the slashes.check [here](https://regex101.com/r/jT5fG2/1)

Comment: thank you very much Arunesh Singh, that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems: 1) unescaped literal backslash in several places and 2) unescaped `.` that matches *any* symbol but  a newline.

When using a verbatim string literal in C# to declare a regex you should remember that to match a literal `\` you need to use two backslashes (`\\`).

[Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=D%3A%5Cfolder1%5Cfolder(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd)%5Csetup.exe&i=D%3A%5Cfolder1%5Cfolder123.234.56.7%5Csetup.exe), your `D:\folder1\folder(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d)\setup.exe` regular expression does not match due to the same reason.

When using double backslashes (*and escaped dot* to match a literal `.`!) - `D:\\folder1\\folder(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d)\\setup\.exe` - [it works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=D%3A%5C%5Cfolder1%5C%5Cfolder(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd)%5C%5Csetup%5C.exe&i=D%3A%5Cfolder1%5Cfolder123.234.56.7%5Csetup.exe).